# Java: How to receive commands from CLI

Tags: java, php, command-line-interface

I have to make a Java program that runs constantly in background and listen to commands sent from the CLI.
For example here's a possible workflow:

1. the user starts the Java program (the program startup can take several minutes because it has to load a lot of data from a database);
2. the user wants to retrive datas from the program via CLI;
3. the program in a matter of seconds has to handle the request and provide a result.

Please note that the step 2 and 3 can occur more than once.

The interface to the user must be via CLI, as the program must provide the results to a PHP script.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, why didn't it work?

Comment: Run it as background service and provide inter process comms to communicate with it (this is technically two processes). You could run the data management in a background thread, but the user closes the console, you will lose the program...

Comment: You're making a rest api or similar then. Stupid question... If Java code and Php do run on the same machine is it still useful to make a Java application to fetch the data and not do it directly from php?

Comment: @fge No, I've haven't tried anythig. Actually, I don't know where to start.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you please provide us some examples?

Comment: @MarcoMura Because the Java program needs to keep the datas loaded in a complex stucture for efficiency.

Comment: Do the work in background threads and let the main thread read from and write to `System.in` and `System.out`. Just treat the CLI as you would treat a GUI. You don't need any fancy rest api and background service here.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker the commands are sent by different instances of PHP, so a "static" instance of the Java program is required.